# Sole proprietor paying expenses from personal account

Tags: germany, expenses, sole-proprietorship

A couple of business invoices have been debited off my personal bank account instead of the business account recently and I am wondering about how to account for this.

In essence, I don't really need to reimburse myself for those expenses, but I need to account for them as an expense on my books somehow, right?

I am using Wave as my accounting software if it helps.

How do I handle this?

Comment: Why not a ledger account specifically named “reimburse self for expenses inadvertently pulled from individual checking account”, with sub-accounts for each “real” expense account?  Then you reverse out of the sub-account into the real expense account?

Answer (score 2):

Record it as an expense and the other side of the transactions comes out of "Owner Contributions."  You essentially made an Owner Contribution each time you used personal funds for a business purchase.

Inversely, if you ever accidentally use business funds for a personal purchase, you would record it out of "Owner Drawings."

Your accounting software may not have separate Owner Contributions and Owner Drawings accounts.  In that case, they can be lumped together into a simple Owner's Equity account.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a private account (Privatkonto) in your accounting where you account for funds which you withdraw from your company or inject into your company. It is a kind of "wormhole" into your private money domain. So you account for

Expense account -> Privat